# What is the fastest bus route from Lugano to Menaggio?

Tags: italy, buses, switzerland

I'm looking to travel from Lugano, Switzerland to Menaggio, Italy in mid-October this year.

I understand the C12 bus is the most direct public transport option, after leaving central Lugano on the #2 bus. [This TripAdvisor guide](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g188095-i739-k8972837-Taking_the_bus_from_Lugano_SBB_Train_Station_to_Menaggio-Lugano_Canton_of_Ticino_Swiss_Alps.html) has fantastic detail and describes my preferred route. Also, I have found the C12 [winter schedule](http://www.asfautolinee.it/wr-resource/upload/ORARI%20PDF/ORARI_INVERNALE/C12.pdf) and [summer schedule](http://www.asfautolinee.it/wr-resource/upload/ORARI%20PDF/ORARI_ESTIVO/C12.pdf) in Italian at asfautolinee.it.

However, when I use the route finder at asfautolinee.it, the fastest route is ~2.5 hours using route #2 -> C16 -> C12.

I suspect the 2.5 hour result appears as the fastest C12 option because the route finder seems to simply use Google Transit (as I sometimes get the response "there are no data in Google Transit for these search criteria") - and Google Transit often doesn't have complete schedule data.

Two questions:

- What dates define the winter and summer periods? Which schedule will apply in October?
- Will I be able to do the trip in ~1 hour, as described in the TripAdvisor post (i.e. despite the route finder's results)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Lugano/Menaggio) shows the C12 route taking 57 minutes (and 15 stops), traveling more directly west-east. [ASF Autolinee](http://asfautolinee.it/content/it/home) also shows an alternative route, the S10 train to a connection with the C10 bus in Como, which takes about 2 hours. Its [C12 route](http://asfautolinee.it/wr-resource/upload/ent3/1/C12.pdf?cbck=wrReq32797) that shows the numerous stops and includes towns that document the 1-hour route (such as Cima, Porlezza, Croce).

The [ASF Autolinee summer schedule](http://asfautolinee.it/content/it/orari-rete-extraurbana) is in effect between 9 June to 11 September; winter schedule begins on 12 September (through 8 June).

To interpret the abbreviations used on the schedule: *Scol* are those that run on school days (scolastici), which include Saturdays. *Fer6* means buses that run Monday-Saturday (all six feriale or working days); Fer5 are for buses that run Monday-Friday. *Fest* indicates Sunday and national holidays (festivo). *Gior* is every day or daily (giornaliero).

Comment: Thank you! This is a fantastic help. In the winter schedule I have linked above, do you know the meaning behind the headings "Scol," "Fer5," "Fer6," etc?

Comment: @Robyn: Scol are those that run on school days (scolastici), which include Saturdays. Fer6 means buses that run Monday-Saturday (all six feriale or working days); Fer5 are for buses that run Monday-Friday. Fest indiates Sunday and holidays (festivo). Gior is every day or daily (giornaliero). I'll add them to the answer, too.

Comment: To elaborate, now that I better understand the PDF schedules and know which one applies in October, I'm comfortable using it as my source of truth and plan to do the ~1 hour C12 journey.

Comment: @Robyn: and if you make a mistake, go with it; it's part of the adventure; how bad can it be, you're in Italy.